React Active Track Player - Is PlaybackActiveTrackChanged buggy? lastIndex does not seem to work
I noticed that PlaybackActiveTrackChanged event of RNTP 4.1.1 provides in lastIndex (same for lastTrack), the index of the track that is before the new active track in the queue but not as it is documented here the index of previously active track.
In the example below, I skip from Index 1 to index 4 in the RNTP queue but the lastIndex provided is 3 (4-1) and not 1.
 LOG  > 1354.554: Event{
          "lastTrack": {
                    "title": "[2/2] Histoire de Marie, femme et sainte",
                    "id": "6760e9ee26ab0e8fd01891b2",
                    "duration": 769,
                    "url": "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.u2gilles.podcastcutter/files/episodes/Au Cœur de l'Histoire /22 Histoire de Marie, femme et sainte",
                    "artwork": "https://static.audiomeans.fr/img/podcast/0a303266-5319-4eb9-85c3-38bacce7785d.jpg",
                    "artist": "Europe 1"
          },
          "lastIndex": 3,
          "track": {
                    "title": "Marignan 1515 : quand la France entre dans la Renaissance",
                    "id": "6760e9e526ab0e8fd01891ad",
                    "duration": 1192,
                    "url": "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.u2gilles.podcastcutter/files/episodes/Entrez dans l'Histoire/Marignan 1515  quand la France entre dans la Renaissance",
                    "artwork": "https://static.audiomeans.fr/img/episode/510df8d5-de40-4ebb-84f8-b5cdccf19f27.jpg",
                    "artist": "Lorànt Deutsch"
          },
          "index": 4,
          "lastPosition": 0,
          "type": "playback-active-track-changed"
}**strong text**

